# Excel VBA copying a filtered selection

Tags: vba, excel, copy, autofilter

I have the following code that filters a column a pastes it in another worksheet

```
 Sub FilterData()
 Dim rlow As Long, erow As Long, erow2 As Long
 Dim av As Variant, bv As Variant
 Dim p As Long, q As Long

 lrow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     
 Worksheets("Wire list").Range("E1").AutoFilter _
 Field:=5, _
 Criteria1:="=S*", _
 VisibleDropDown:=False

 For q = 2 To lrow
      Sheet3.Cells(q, 5).Copy
      erow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
      Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow2, 5)
 Next q

 End Sub
```

The problem is that the cells that are being copied are the ones defined by q, but I want to copy the autofiltered selection. Any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: Just a note to your code: Make sure that you specify a sheet for every `Rows` command like `lrow = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and later in `Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` otherwise it assumes the `ActiveSheet` for `Rows` and this will fail in at least one of these 2 situations in your code. And don't use `Variant` unless you know why you need to, it is evil. In most cases there is a better solution than `Variant`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Peh , I already solved this problem by manually filtering the copy data so I don't have to use autofilter, also, changed the variants to strings (as they were), defined 2 variables as worksheets referred every row command to this variables!